# Highlight one set of data based on if it matches another set of data using Conditional Formatting

Tags: google-sheets, match, conditional-formatting, array-formulas, gs-conditional-formatting

I have 6 columns and ~200 rows of numbers on one Google Sheet. Then on the other is also 6 columns but only 3 rows. I am trying to use conditional formatting to highlight the numbers in the larger group if they match any of the ones one my other sheet of data.

[image]

I've gotten it for matching one number, but having it look at a whole set is proving to be more difficult.

Comment: I suggest you don't link to the image but imbed it in your post using the provided image widget in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

try on range **A2:E**:

```
=(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(A2), "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, $G$2:$K$5)&"$"))*(A1<>"")
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Conditional formatting Apply to range A:A use the following custom formula:

```
=or(A1=$G$1,A1=$G$2,A1=$G$3)
```

This will be the easiest way to do it, of course if you have a lot of matches you want to make then it will become more and more difficult without a helper column... Your example only has 3 matches per column so this will work but if you have hundreds of matches you will need to basically make a column looking up if there is a match and conditional formatting based on that (it will be a lot easier and cleaner).